# refer to stored proc output param in macro?

Tags: teradata

Is there a way to refer to an output parameter of a stored procedure in a macro?

My stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE db.ssis_load_nextID
(IN tbl VARCHAR(30), OUT nextID SMALLINT )
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxID SMALLINT;

    SELECT  MAX(loadID) INTO maxID 
    FROM db.SSIS_Load
    WHERE TABLENAME = tbl
    GROUP BY TABLENAME; 

    IF maxID IS NULL THEN
        SET nextID = 1;
    ELSE
        SET nextID = maxID + 1;
    END if;

END;
```

I want to refer to this result in a macro like:

```
CREATE MACRO db.tbSTG_m AS ( 
INSERT  INTO db.tbProd (ID1, ID2, f1, f2, ..., fn, loadID)  
SELECT  ID1, ID2, f1, f2,..., fn,
         CALL db.ssis_Load_nextID('tbProd',nextID)  
FROM    db.tbstg 
; );
```

because running `CALL db.ssis_Load_nextID('tbProd',nextID)` returns the result I want in the first (only) row of the first (only) column.

I tried storing the result in a variable in the macro, but apparently, that's unsupported.

Also, I'd like to start with an empty SSIS_load table, so it creates the first row when the first table is loaded, instead of pre-populating the load table before the automated load process starts.

All help appreciated,

-Beth

fyi, We got it to work by removing the '`group by tablename`' clause and embedding the sp in the macro:

```
CREATE  MACRO db.tbSTG_m AS ( 
   INSERT   INTO db.tbProd  
   SELECT   ID1, ID2, f1, f2, ..., fn (
      SELECT    ZEROIFNULL(MAX(loadID))+1 
      FROM   db.ssis_load 
      WHERE TABLENAME = 'tbStg') mx 
   FROM db.tbSTG;
);
```

Comment: Are you trying to use a stored proc to generate a key?

Comment: no, I need to look up the next available ID

Comment: Assuming everything is done within the same session, have the stored procedure write the value out to a global temporary table, then cross join to that gtt in your insert statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a stored proc for that (you would have to use a UDF not a procedure)

however you can do it in your macro

syntax may not be 100% correct.. working from memory but should get you close

I am assuming tbl is a parameter passed in correct?

basically you join to the id table and use that in your insert...

then you update the id table with the maximum freshly inserted ids

```
  CREATE MACRO db.tbSTG_m AS ( 



  INSERT  INTO db.tbProd (ID1, ID2, f1, f2, ..., fn, loadID)  

  SELECT ID1, ID2, f1, f2,..., fn, MAXloadID + SUM(1) OVER(ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) 
  FROM    db.tbstg 
  cross join (SELECT  MAX(loadID) as MAXloadID 
      FROM db.SSIS_Load
      WHERE TABLENAME = tbl
      GROUP BY TABLENAME) as IDGEN
  ; 

  update db.SSIS_Load from (select MAX(loadID) as MAXloadID from  tbl) as upid
  set loadID = upid.MAXloadID
  where db.SSIS_Load.TABLENAME = tbl

  );
```

Comment: what I really want is to store the maxLoadID result in a variable and reference it twice, but macros don't allow you to declare variables.

Comment: why not do the whole thing in a stored procedure? what are you requirements for this?